# Parsing JSON string in android

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

Parsing JSON seems like it is a pretty common topic of discussion on here.  I have looked around and still have not found what I am looking for.
Here is my code for my HttpClient

```
public class CreateJsonRequest {


    public static String SendJsonRequest(String URL, Map<String,Object> params){
            try{
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);

                JSONObject holder = new JSONObject();

                for (Map.Entry<String, Object> m : params.entrySet()){
                    try {
                        holder.put(m.getKey(), m.getValue());
                    }
                    catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("Hmmmm", "JSONException : "+e);
                    }
                }   
                StringEntity se;
                se = new StringEntity(holder.toString());

                httpPost.setEntity(se);
                httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "text/json");
                httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "text/json");

                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                if(entity != null){
                    final JSONObject respObject = new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
                    String result = respObject.toString();      
                    parseJSON(result);
```

I am using a HttpClient to send a JSON request to a server.  The server then returns a response in JSON.  This works great.  Now here is where I am running into trouble.
I am receiving an HttpEntity from the server. I am then turning that into a string which looks like this. `{"Make":"Ford","Year": 1975, "Model":"Mustang"}`  I want to be able to send this string to my `parseJSON(String jString)` method and it return a key value map.  Where I feel this differs from other posts is that I want the parse method to be able to create a key value map for any JSON string I send it. So if I sent it `{"Engine":"v8","Cylinders": 8, "Transmission":"Manual","Gears": 4}` it would still work.  Is this doable? And if so, could you give me some nudges in the right direction?

Comment: try using Google's GSON library, its awesome!

Comment: This isn't `Android`, right? Or am I missing something? It seems completely irrelevant that you use it in an android app.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In this case you can use the `keys` method of the `JSONObject` class. It will basically returns an `Iterator` of the keys, that you can then iterate to get and put the values in a map:

```
try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(theJsonString);
    Iterator keys = jsonObject.keys();
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    while (keys.hasNext()) {
        String key = (String) keys.next();
        map.put(key, jsonObject.getString(key));
    }
    System.out.println(map);// this map will contain your json stuff
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Ah...I didn't even think about that.  All of the examples I saw were using known keys...yes that should work. I'll try it in a bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Note that [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) can deserialize either of the two JSON examples very simply.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> values = mapper.readValue(theJsonString, Map.class);
```

[Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson) can do it similarly simply if you're satisfied with a `Map<String, String>`, instead of a `Map<String, Object>`.  Currently, Gson would need custom deserialization for a `Map<String, Object>`.