# How to parse jsons response in android

Tags: android

I am getting response in this way:

```
{
    agentCode: 9911223344,
    transId: 337450,
    resultCode: 0,
    resultDesc: Transaction Successful,
    dealList = [1, EST1], [2, EST2], [3, EST3]
}
```

I have to fetch data under dealList ,kindly tell me how can i do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON string in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308193/parsing-json-string-in-android)

Comment: This doesnt looks like a valid json as there is an '=' sign after dealList

Comment: whether ":" instead of "="

Comment: acooding to you what is valid format for dealListing

Comment: this is not a json content.

Comment: See my answer, you cannot use such message as JSON.

Comment: That is a not a valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You have invalid formatted `json` message.
First of all you cannot use `[ ]` because according `json` specification is assumes that this will be an array. 
You have to change these entries to the object ones `{ }`.
You have to manually parse it, BTW as a plain string, or make `json` message valid and use libraries - [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) or [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)

Here is valid `json` that I would use in your case

```
{
    "agentCode": 9911223344,
    "transId": 337450,
    "resultCode": 0,
    "resultDesc": "Transaction Successful",
    "dealList": [{
        "id": 1,
        "value": "EST1"
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "value": "EST2"
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "value": "EST3"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an invalid json string.

You can check if it valid or not by this page 
http://jsonlint.com/

For json parser, you can simple parse json use default functions of Android SDK

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm